# Hibernate complex sort via computed field

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Having some performance issues when attempting to sort a list of parent/child entities - currently I have mapped an entity "view" and I sort by this sub-select, but have some scaling issues.

I'll try and simplify the scenario somewhat;

Both parent and child extend a base class - which contains an `ID` and `name`. When showing a parent in the client we display its `name`, and when showing a child we show a concatenation of its parent `name` and its own. *(E.g. `parent1`, `parent1.child1`, `parent1.child2` etc)*

The requirement is that when showing a list, parents and children are grouped together, as the natural sort based on the name shown would be as such.
*(E.g. `parent1`, `parent1.child1`, `parent1.child2`, `parent2`, `parent3.child1` etc)*

We are using `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)` - and the child does not capture the name of it's parent - they are referenced by the primary key (`ID`). De-normalising this data is not an option as renames are common and there can be hundreds of thousands of child objects per parent, this would be too costly.

Here is a brief overview of the classes;

```
public class BaseClass {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    Parent parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<BaseId> baseId;
}
```

```
@DiscriminatorValue("PARENT")
public class Parent extends BaseClass {

}
```

```
@DiscriminatorValue("CHILD")
public class Child extends BaseClass {

}
```

And we have also mapped the `Subselect` to the `BaseClass`;

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Subselect(
        "SELECT 0 as id, N'' as primaryId, N'' as secondaryId WHERE 0=1 \n" +
        "UNION ALL\n" +
        "SELECT base.id, base.name, null \n"+
        "FROM sec.BaseClass base \n" +
        "WHERE base.parent_sid IS NULL \n" +
        "UNION ALL \n" +
        "SELECT child.id, parent.name, child.name \n"+
        "FROM sec.BaseClass child \n" +
        "INNER JOIN sec.BaseClass parent ON child.parent_sid=parent.sid \n"
        )
@Synchronize({ "BaseClass" })
public class BaseId {
    // Fields etc
}
```

With the above in place, we then have the ability to select a page via rest and then sort as required, e.g. `/api/base?sort=baseId.primaryId,asc&sort=baseId.secondaryId,arc`

Note: built around this we have a lot of specifications which makes the query relatively dynamic based on the rest filters supplied, e.g. you can also search by name while sorting in this way. So switching to native queries is also unfortunately not an option for us.

As mentioned, this doesn't scale - the dataset we are currently working towards has 5 millions parent/child rows (roughly broken down as 1:10000 parent/child).

EDIT: This is a paged response from the database

Are there any suggestions with how to sort in this way but without the performance cost?

Comment: Are you using `Pageable` ?

Comment: @Eklavya yes this is a paged response